# which date format looks like this: 46:53.4

Tags: python, date, format

I am processing a dataset with a date column in it. But the date format is strange to me:

date
59:06.4
42:42.9
07:18.0
......

I have never seen this format before. Could anyone let me know what this format is? and if I use python to process it, what functions I should use?

Comment: This doesn’t look like a date. May be a time format?

Comment: This looks like a time format, Try HH.mm.S .

Comment: First part could be `minute` or `second` and same for second part because both has range from `0-59` and last part is hour. `59:06.4` it could be `ss:mm.H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know. This is the date + time format. When I read it in python. It automatically transfer into datetime format